# How can I get an integer from a string in Java?

Tags: java

I am using the following:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
```

Are there any other ways to get an integer from a string? If the number is really small as it is then doe the Byte and Char objects provide something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There's:

```
Byte.parseByte(s); -- parses a Byte from a String
Short.parseShort(s); -- parses a Short from a String
```

And for larger numbers there's:

```
Long.parseLong(s);
-- Float is an imprecise representation of a floating point number using 32 bits
Float.parseFloat(s);
-- Double is an imprecise representation of a floating point number using 64 bits
Double.parseDouble(s);
-- BigIntegers is an integer of arbitrary size as is accurate
new BigInteger(s);
-- BigDecimal is a floating point number of arbitrary size as is accurate
new BigDecimal(s);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: int i4 = new BigInteger(args[3]); Type mismatch: cannot convert from BigInteger to int

Comment: To get an `int` from a `BigInteger` use `.intValue()`: ie `i4 = new BigInteger(s).intValue();`. The `BigInteger` class is for performing accurate integer arithmetic on arbitrarily large numbers. It has special methods for such arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Short.parseShort(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#parseShort%28java.lang.String%29) and [Byte.parseByte(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String%29) wrapper methods to parse smaller integer values.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways to get an integer from a `String`:

```
    String value = "2";

    int i = Integer.valueOf(value);
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(value);
    i = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also should wrap that in a try catch block so your code will not blow up if you try to pass it a non-integer value.